# Css 100 viewport width being more than screen width?

Tags: html, css

[image]

The problem is  about-me section is slightly more wider than the header section even though they both have the same width.You can even observe this in the picture. Blue background is header section inspected in console and white area is the about me section This is also showing the side navigation bar on the bottom which is trouble some.

```
 <!--Header Section   -->
    <section id="header">
        <div class="header-bg-overlay">
            <div class="header-bg">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="hero-content">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="about-me">
        <div class="about-section">

        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

h5{
    color:white;
    font-size:75px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h4{
    color:white;
    font-size:55px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header-bg{
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    background: url('../assets/background.jpg')no-repeat center;
    background-position: -30px -80px;
}

#about-me{
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Ca you demo this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the  width of both the sections to 100%

Comment: I want to know what is problem with my viewport logic

Comment: Thanks it worked but what is the problem with viewport

Comment: Look there is a problem with view port it  sets itself according to the view  ao the major problem with it is that in small screen it decreases its width very much and vise versa for the large screen hope you getting it. Try to use viewport with mostly logos

Comment: @UnityHour It has been 4 years now :) but if you want to know why you face this problem, read my answer

Answer (score 0):

vw = document + scrollbar.

Fix:

```css
.header-bg, #about-me {
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how your solution solve the problem ?

Comment: @Guillaume S When we put some extra-content, like height:200vh, we have scrollbar, and now 100vw more, than we need. This fix limits the width by parent.

Answer (score 0):

Space and new line characters in your HTML code are rendered as one-character space in the browser. Because of that, actually there is another element in addition to the box with 100vw and 100vh dimensions and this causes the overflow.

You have two options:

1. Remove the new line and space characters before the opening tag and after the closing tag of the .header-bg element. These tags should be in touch with the tags of the parent element.
2. Use display:flex on parent element. Contrary to other display options, flexbox does not render space characters around its children.